# UIDocumentInteractionController 'Mail' option pre-fill with recipients

Tags: objective-c, email, reference, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I am making use of UIDocumentInteractionController. When the user selects the 'Mail' option I would like to pre-fill the MFMailComposeViewController with some emails. Is this possible and if so how? I have tried overriding presentViewController:animate:completion to see if the MFMailComposeViewController is also presented from the same viewController as the UIDocumentInteractionController is presented; that did not work. In simple words I need to get a reference to the MFMailComposeViewController instance that is presented when the user selects 'Mail' from the options menu..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems how I was trying to solve my problem was not possible. The only way to go around this is to have your own mail button mapped to an IBAction with code that results in an MFMailComposeViewController being instantiated and given the mail recipients and the document as an attachment.